# My Unanswered Question Is Not On Unanswered, But Answered Questions Are

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

Here's my question: [How To Let My MBP know that a USB is bootable?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335906/how-to-let-my-mbp-know-that-a-usb-is-bootable) . I just realized that my unanswered question is not on /unanswered, but many answered questions with over 10 votes and 4 answers are. I don't understand why this is happening.

(edit)

The question is recently answered, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for seeking help here on Meta! :) It might just be me, but I just wanted to clarify that I'm understanding the issue you're seeing. Are you saying that you're not seeing *unanswered* questions listed under the unanswered filter, but that you're seeing many *answered* questions listed there instead? Or...?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Answer (score 2):

When I go to https://apple.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest, I can see your question:

[image]

There should be no exception for your own questions; it's not mentioned in the [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18871/295232) and I can see one of my own unanswered questions in the list as well. It *is* possible for a question to appear there even with 4 answers:

> The Unanswered Questions tab [shows questions that have no answers with a positive score nor an accepted answer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R03gE.png) (That includes questions with no answers at all.)

Comment: This implies I do not know why *you* didn't/don't see your own question. SE developers will notice this question since you tagged it as a [bug]; whether they will be able to provide an answer and solve it, I'm not sure. I can imagine this doesn't have high priority for them.